# loop through array mustache template with key value pair

Tags: loops, templates, mustache

this is input array which I wanna use to generate template to use non-empty list of mustache:

```
[{
    "name": "resque"
}, {
    "name": "hub"
}, {
    "name": "rip"
}]
```

following is the template I wanna use for non-empty mustache list :-

```
{{#}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>
{{/}}
```

my desired output should be as follows which should print all names for the array I've provided as input to loop over.:

```
<b>resque</b>
<b>hub</b>
<b>rip</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the API.
https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Object:

```
{
  "stooges": [
    { "name": "Moe" },
    { "name": "Larry" },
    { "name": "Curly" }
  ]
}
```

Template:

```
{{#stooges}}
<b>{{name}}</b>
{{/stooges}}
```

Result:

```
<b>Moe</b>
<b>Larry</b>
<b>Curly</b>
```